# Is it possible to completely disable PostgreSQL roles, users, permissions etc

Tags: postgresql

In 99% of my use cases I don't need any of that stuff. Is it possible to completely disable it in PostgreSQL? All those users, roles, permissions etc...

Comment: Better match for [dba.se]

Comment: You cannot disable them, but they won't bother you.

Just use a single user for everything, then that user can do everything with all the objects he created and consequently owns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can completely *disable* the user/role system as Postgres is a client/server architecture and you will need user/role etc. to connect to the server.

But you can *bypass* it by setting up your default account, e.g. your username if you are using Unix/Linux as a database super user, or `GRANT` it all necessary privileges.

You can also modify the postgres configuration file, e.g. at `/etc/postgresql/9.x/main/pg_hba.conf` and change certain authentication method to `trust`, e.g., to trust any connections from the local machine:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
#host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
#host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

You can also store your password in a `.pgpass` file, but mind the security risks there.

Answer (score 3):

No, it isn't.

But you can, if you really insist, just set everything to `trust` in `pg_hba.conf` and use the `postgres` superuser for everything.

I hope your systems are completely isolated from the Internet and accept no external user input of any kind though. Because those features are there for a reason. Even if your app is behind a middleware layer, etc, you should at minimum be using a non-superuser for normal app operations. Preferably also one who doesn't own the tables and is just GRANTed the needed access. This will help limit the damage from various possible attacks through your middleware layer.